# How Do I configure my Xcode project to run on multiple version of iOS?

Tags: ios, xcode

I have already created my app using Xcode 9 and deployment target to be 11.4.
One of my requirements is for the app to be compatible with the latest version of iOS back to iOS 8. when I change the deployment target to iOS8 the app won't build.
illegal configuration
Safe Area Layout Guide before iOS 9. 
Is there anything I can do easily to fix this problem? configuration settings for my project somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to your storyboard(s), open the `File inspector` and uncheck `Use Safe Area Layout Guides`.

See:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: thank you didn't know where to look for that. It compiles now. I have been asked to do this assessment project for a job interview, I am very green when it comes to the configuration and pretty much everything. I have uploaded my git repository to git hub. Does it mater what deployment target I save in my project in the repository should I use the latest 11.4?

Comment: I do no understand your question. You said you have to support iOS 8. That means you have to set the deployment target accordingly.

Comment: What I am trying to ask is if set the deployment target to iOS 8 from the settings it will be fine for iOS 8 onwards. Will the app work on a later version lets say the latest 11.4 if the deployment target is set to iOS 8?

Comment: Yes it will. This setting defines the **minimum** deployment target. Meaning the app will work on iOS 8 and upwards.

Comment: Thanks very much Andre. You have been a great help for me. Really appreciate it

Comment: Glad I could help. Maybe you can mark my answer as correct as soon as you are able to.